# How to target Drupal CSS Injector rule at a CiviCRM profile, using query string paramters

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to target a Drupal CSS Injector rule at a specific Civi profile, using the query string parameter that identifies the profile.

There is a section in the CSS Injector dialogue 'Add the CSS on specific pages'. It's v easy to use 'add on only the listed pages' with a path and wildcards as required, but that can't target a specific profile. For that I'm imagining I could use the option 'Add if the following PHP code outputs a nonzero value' to target a specific profile by using the profile id in the query params.

I assume that could work - ? The problem is this is very difficult to test because any mistake in the php will irretrievably break the entire site.

Does anyone have an opinion on whether this is a correct or sensible thing to be attempting and/or a working example of using the nonzero php option?

PS I know I could add targeted css via the Drupal theme, but if I could do it via the UI that would be very much easier in my current setup.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly something you can do, but as you probably realize it's fragile, hard to maintain and hard to test, so not a great idea if you can avoid it. You could do something like:

`<?php $url = request_uri(); if (strpos($url, "civicrm/profile/create?gid=NNN")) { return TRUE; } ?>`

Comment: Thanks @Lars SG. I agree this is very much to be avoided - I wonder if there is really any valid use case? Note I answered my own question.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I looked a bit harder and found that there is a suitable css class in the html:

<div class="crm-contribution-page-id-6 crm-block crm-contribution-main-form-block" data-page-id="6" data-page-template="main">

this class: crm-contribution-page-id-6